# Calculate difference and percent change on a list of controls

Tags: vba, powerpoint

What would be the best way, within VBA, to accomplish the following:

1. I have two groups of controls which represent a historical and a current data set
2. I am using the control.tag field to dictate which is historical and which is current, as an example:

   - Group 1 contains (Historical Data)

     - Historical - Number of People
     - Historical - Number of Cars
     - Historical - Number of Houses
   - Group 2 contains (Current Data)

     - Current - Number of People
     - Current - Number of Cars
     - Current - Number of Houses
3. I would like to loop through both sets of controls and provide the following for each set

   - Change in value (ex: (Current - NUmber of People) - (Historical - Number of People))
   - Percentage change (ex: (((Current - NUmber of People) - (Historical - Number of People)) / (Historical - Number of People)) * 100)
4. I'm hoping to avoid having to call each control manually but would rather want to loop through all controls, find the ones that match in each set and do the math.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to loop through all shapes on a slide. Find which ones are ActiveX controls (If oShape.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then), get the .Text properties of the ActiveX controls, turn those into numbers with operators like CInt, if needed, then do the math.